# Using loops to create multiple crosstables in R

Tags: r, loops, lapply, crosstab, crosstable

I have a dataset with one main categorical outcome variable and multiple categorical exposure variables. I'd like to generate a series of individual crosstabs with Chi Square tests for each exposure variable, and I'm wondering if there's a way to do that using a loop.

This is essentially the long version of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
    ctable(data$x1, data$y, chisq=T, useNA='no')
    ctable(data$x2, data$y, chisq=T, useNA='no')
    ctable(data$x3, data$y, chisq=T, useNA='no')
```

This was my first pass at turning that into a loop:

```
    for(i in c('x1', 'x2', 'x3')){
    ctables <- ctable(data[[i]], data$y, chisq=T, useNA='no')
    }
    ctables
```

I don't get any errors when I run that, but it only returns a ctable for the last variable name (in this example, x3). What am I missing?

Note: I need to specifically name the data frame (data$y as opposed to just saying y) because I'm working with a large SQL database that includes multiple data frames.

Comment: you are inadvertently writing over `ctables` on each iteration of the loop, and this is why `ctables` only hold the last result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lapply()` instead:

```
ctables <- lapply(c('x1', 'x2', 'x3'), function(i) {
  ctable(data[[i]], data$y, chisq=T, useNA='no', dnn =c(i,"y"))
})
```

** Updated with `dnn=c(i,"y")` to specify explicit names in resulting `ctable`

Comment: As a follow-up to this though, do you know how I can get the x variable names to appear in the ctables? Right now it's just showing up as "data$[[i]] * data$y" in the ctable titles, as opposed to "data$x1 * data$y".

Comment: Sure, see my addition to the answer. Basically, you can use the `dnn` argument within `ctable()`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use the package `{crosstable}` which allows you to ask for several variables as input.

Here is an example using the `mtcars` dataset:

```r
library(crosstable)
crosstable(mtcars2, c(am, gear, cyl), by=vs, total=TRUE, 
           test=TRUE, showNA='no', percent_digits=1) %>% 
  as_flextable()
```

[image: crosstable]